# android - get resource id from gallery

Tags: android, resources, gallery, drawable

So i have a program with a `Gallery` (made with pictures from the resources folder), a Button and an `ImageView`

I want to choose one of the images from the gallery, press the button, and change the `ImageView` bitmap to display the one selected from the gallery...

I have the changing methods from activity to activity all fixed... but i'm just having trouble getting the **id** of the image picked, the **integer**, **drawable**, long, string... or whatever it helps...

Here's the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

            Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
            g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

            g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                    //CODE TO KNOW IF PICKED THE 1ST OR 2ND IMAGE

                    //Toast.makeText(Galeria.this, v.getId() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Toast.makeText(Galeria.this, parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position) + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Toast.makeText(Galeria.this, id + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
            });
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;

    private Integer[] mImageId = {
            R.drawable.image1, //first image 
            R.drawable.image2, //second image
    };

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        TypedArray a = c.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() 
        return mImageId.length;         
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);          

        i.setImageResource(mImageId[position]); 

        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(400, 225));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

        return i;
    }
}
```

The three Toast there on the `OnItemClick` void are my attempts of showing the id... but only showing the position of the image from the gallery.

Is there any other solution? I've read something about the dynamics ids... but could understand well...

Where should I put the code to get my desired id??

Any Help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                //CODE TO KNOW IF PICKED THE 1ST OR 2ND IMAGE
                int imageId = (Integer) (parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                myImageView.setImageResource(imageId);
                //Toast.makeText(Galeria.this, v.getId() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Toast.makeText(Galeria.this, parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position) + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Toast.makeText(Galeria.this, id + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
        });
```

In your adapter getItem should return the object of the dataset

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
        return (mImageId[position]);
 }
```

Comment: I like your solutions thanks! but i get this errors at this line:


`int imageId = ((ImageAdapter)parent).getItem(position);`



**Multiple markers at this line
- Type mismatch: Cannot convert from Object to int
- Cannot cast from AdapterView to Galeria.ImageAdapter**

Even trying to solve the type mismatch i still get the 2nd error i don't understan

Comment: still get the **- Cannot cast from AdapterView to Galeria.ImageAdapter**

Comment: use directly parent.getItemAtPosition(position). I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the `image view` `resource` as `drawable` on your `itemClickListener` :

```
(ImageView)view.getBackground()
```

This will return image as drawable of selected image view's resource.